# Сan't get tiles using mapbox from geoserver

Tags: gis, mapbox, geoserver, mapbox-gl, mbtiles

I ran into a problem that I can not correctly connect to the Mapbox. At the front, he gives this error.[image of frontend Mapbox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYuso.png).
in the logs on the server, I get this: [image of GeoServer logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUzEv.jpg)

I connect to the geoserver like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Mapbox GL</title>

  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

<script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = '<redacted>';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [37.61, 55.7],
      zoom: 2
  });

  map.on('load', function() {
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "water_name_id",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": {
            "type": "vector",
            "scheme": "tms",
            "tiles": ['http://130.193.43.240:8084/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=cite:water_name&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:3857:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:3857&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}'],
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 14,
            'tileSize': 512
        },
        "source-layer": "water_name",
        "paint": {
            "fill-opacity": 0.6,
            "fill-color": "rgb(53, 175, 109)",
            'fill-outline-color': 'white'
        }
    });
  });
  
  </script>
</html>
```

And this [link to the source code](https://git.infosys.ifv.systems/Dmitri.Sirobokov/geoserver_fork/-/blob/a9d0a57f088c1c6a56057e9449be3ceb9adac7ad/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/ows/LocalWorkspaceCallback.java) where executed logs:

```
03 Dec 11:17:12 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not lookup context {0] as a workspace, trying as group
```

I would be glad to read any tips or answers:)

Comment: Have you found a solution ?